# Как определить систему счисления для задаваемого числа?

Tags: javascript, системы-счисления

Как написать код, который будет определять систему счисления (2, 8, 10, 16) для задаваемого числа.

Comment: И каким образом вы собираетесь определить 1000 это 2, 8, 10 или 16-ричная система?)

Comment: Если известно значение этого числа в десятичной системе?

Comment: @Isaev обычным образом) 1000 - это 2, 8, 10, и 16-ричная система одновременно!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var chislo = prompt("Enter number:");
if (chislo) {
  var base2 = "01";
  var base8 = "01234567";
  var base10 = "0123456789";
  var base16 = "0123456789ABCDEF";

  var b2 = true;
  var b8 = true;
  var b10 = true;
  var b16 = true;

  chislo = chislo.toUpperCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < chislo.length; i++) {
    if (b2 && base2.indexOf(chislo[i]) == -1)
      b2 = false;
    if (b8 && base8.indexOf(chislo[i]) == -1)
      b8 = false;
    if (b10 && base10.indexOf(chislo[i]) == -1)
      b10 = false;
    if (b16 && base16.indexOf(chislo[i]) == -1)
      b16 = false;
  }
  console.log(b2, b8, b10, b16);
}
```